# pandas multiindex sort by specified rules

Tags: pandas

There is a dataframe like below

```
arrays = [
    np.array(["baz", "baz", "bar", "bar", "qux",  "foo"]),
    np.array(["yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes",   "no"]),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(6,4)), index=arrays)
df
```

[image]

Now want to know the `yes_rate`(yes/all) of each column
[image]

the implement code as below

```
first_index_list = list(df.index.get_level_values(0).unique())
for index in first_index_list:
    index_sum = df.loc[index].sum()
    if df.index.isin([(index,'yes')]).any():
        yes_rate = df.loc[(index, 'yes')] / index_sum    
        df.loc[(index, 'yes_rate'),:] = yes_rate
    df.loc[(index,'All'),:] = index_sum
    

df.sort_index()
```

but the code is not ideal, there are some problems,

1. how to sort as below order

```
first index: [baz,bar,qux,foo] just as first picture
second index: [no,yes,All,yes_rate]
```

2. repeat execute the code, `All` and `yes_rate` values not change
   So how to only add `yes` and `no` to generate `All` （note: `yes` and `no` not guaranteed to exist）

```
index_sum = ...
if yes exists:
    index_sum += df.loc[(index, 'yes')]
if no exists:
    index_sum += df.loc[(index, 'no')]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `pandas.concat` to concatenate in the desired order, then only sort the first level:

```
l = ['baz', 'bar', 'qux', 'foo']
order = pd.Series({k:v for v,k in enumerate(l)})

df_all = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
out = (pd
  .concat([df,
           pd.concat({'All': df_all,
                      'yes_rate': df.xs('yes', level=1).div(df_all)})
             .dropna(how='all')
             .swaplevel()
          ],)
  .sort_index(level=0, key=order.reindex, sort_remaining=False)
)
```

output:

```
                       0           1           2          3
baz yes        20.000000   97.000000   95.000000  38.000000
    no         85.000000   73.000000   23.000000  27.000000
    All       105.000000  170.000000  118.000000  65.000000
    yes_rate    0.190476    0.570588    0.805085   0.584615
bar yes        86.000000   32.000000   73.000000  16.000000
    no          9.000000   97.000000    2.000000  55.000000
    All        95.000000  129.000000   75.000000  71.000000
    yes_rate    0.905263    0.248062    0.973333   0.225352
qux yes        69.000000   16.000000   92.000000  82.000000
    All        69.000000   16.000000   92.000000  82.000000
    yes_rate    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000   1.000000
foo no         77.000000    5.000000   12.000000   3.000000
    All        77.000000    5.000000   12.000000   3.000000
```

Comment: Tks! could solve second problem, but how to sort multiindex as custom order?

Comment: Use a custom key, see update

Comment: Tks! Does sort_index could support multi index? e.g. list1.index(first) * 10 + list2.index(second). Want to second index also sort as custom order, e.g. [no, yes,All,yes_rate]

Comment: In this case, better use a separate column with your operation and sort on that

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    if ss.name=='level_1':
        ss[6]='yes_rate'
        ss[-1]='ALL'
    else:
        ss[6]=ss.iloc[0]/ss.sum()
        ss[-1]=ss.sum()
    return ss.sort_index()

df.reset_index().groupby('level_0').apply(lambda dd:dd.apply(function1).set_index('level_1'))


#%%
                         0           1           2           3
level_0 level_1                                                 
bar     ALL       164.506098  136.514706  176.511364   83.012048
        yes        83.000000   70.000000   90.000000    1.000000
        no         81.000000   66.000000   86.000000   82.000000
        yes_rate    0.506098    0.514706    0.511364    0.012048
baz     ALL       100.310000   32.281250   35.228571  143.342657
        yes        31.000000    9.000000    8.000000   49.000000
        no         69.000000   23.000000   27.000000   94.000000
        yes_rate    0.310000    0.281250    0.228571    0.342657
foo     ALL        52.000000   29.000000   29.000000   35.000000
        no         51.000000   28.000000   28.000000   34.000000
        yes_rate    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
qux     ALL         7.000000   65.000000   33.000000   57.000000
        yes         6.000000   64.000000   32.000000   56.000000
        yes_rate    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
```